# Group Concat having giving weird results

Tags: mysql

I have this SQL query :

```
SELECT v.*,  group_concat(distinct(vi.interest_id)) as interests, group_concat(distinct(vs.skill_id)) as skills, vc.date_from
FROM `vacancies` as v
LEFT JOIN `vacancy_interests` as vi on v.vacancy_id = vi.vacancy_id
LEFT JOIN `vacancy_skills` as vs on v.vacancy_id = vs.vacancy_id
LEFT JOIN `vacancy_calendar` as vc on v.vacancy_id = vc.vacancy_id
WHERE v.vacancy_visibility_end_date >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY v.vacancy_id
```

Consider this query returning the following results (the 3 last columns are the ones discussed in this question):

```
vacancy_id,org_id,name,description,number_required,occupancy_kind,website,offer,logo,banner,address_country,address_city,address_postal_code,address_line_1,address_line_2,vacancy_visibility_start_date,vacancy_visibility_end_date,engagement,interests,skills,date_from

    "2","1","test123","aze<sdgqswdfg","1","1","","blabla",NULL,"12049394_10208129537615226_4853636504350654671_n.jpg","Belgie","Brussel","1000","Brusselsestraat 15",NULL,"2016-09-02 00:00:00","2016-09-19 00:00:00","3","13,6,1","4,3","2016-09-13 00:00:00"
    "3","1","blablabla","lkpjoip","1","2","","blabla",NULL,NULL,"Belgie","Antwerpen","2000","Antwerpsestraat 16",NULL,"2016-09-02 00:00:00","2016-09-29 00:00:00","3","28","7,8,5","2016-09-01 00:00:00"
    "4","1","hahaha","14556dsf","1","3","","blabla",NULL,NULL,"Belgie","Mechelen","2800","Mechelsesteenweg 17",NULL,"2016-09-02 00:00:00","2016-09-28 00:00:00","3",NULL,NULL,"2016-09-26 00:00:00"
    "5","1","omggg","45sdfdj5","1","1","","blabla",NULL,NULL,"Belgie","Gent","3000","Gentsesteenweg 18",NULL,"2016-09-02 00:00:00","2016-09-30 00:00:00","3","17,11","4,1","2016-09-19 00:00:00"
    "6","1","this is a test","wauhiufdsq","1","2","","blabla",NULL,NULL,"Belgie","Luik","4000","Luikseweg 19",NULL,"2016-09-02 00:00:00","2016-09-30 00:00:00","3","19,17,22","6","2016-08-10 00:00:00"
```

Note that the vacancy interests and vacancy skills table can contain multiple records for a single vacancy. E.g. It could be that vacancy 3 has 3 rows with all different interest_id's. The group_concat solves my problem here. 
So this query works fine as it should.

However, 2 problems I encountered are the following:

1) When I add a filter in HAVING on the interests by an ID this only returns me one row instead of the expected two rows.

```
SELECT v.*,  group_concat(distinct(vi.interest_id)) as interests, group_concat(distinct(vs.skill_id)) as skills, vc.date_from
FROM `vacancies` as v
LEFT JOIN `vacancy_interests` as vi on v.vacancy_id = vi.vacancy_id
LEFT JOIN `vacancy_skills` as vs on v.vacancy_id = vs.vacancy_id
LEFT JOIN `vacancy_calendar` as vc on v.vacancy_id = vc.vacancy_id
WHERE v.vacancy_visibility_end_date >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY v.vacancy_id
HAVING interests IN (17)
```

This returns me only one row. Namely record with vacanacy_id 5, while it should also obviously also return vacancy_id = 6.

**The thing that is the weirdest to me is that if I do the exact same thing but for skills (HAVING skills IN (4)), this does return me multiple rows with the correct result.**

2) When I want to filter on the date_from (together with the interests and skills in the HAVING, I do the following:

```
SELECT v.*,  group_concat(distinct(vi.interest_id)) as interests, group_concat(distinct(vs.skill_id)) as skills, vc.date_from
FROM `vacancies` as v
LEFT JOIN `vacancy_interests` as vi on v.vacancy_id = vi.vacancy_id
LEFT JOIN `vacancy_skills` as vs on v.vacancy_id = vs.vacancy_id
LEFT JOIN `vacancy_calendar` as vc on v.vacancy_id = vc.vacancy_id
WHERE v.vacancy_visibility_end_date >= CURDATE() AND date(vc.date_from) > '2016-09-10'
GROUP BY v.vacancy_id
HAVING skills IN (4)
```

This will only return me vacancy number 5, while obviously also vacancy number 2 has a date greater than 2016-09-10 (2016-09-13 00:00:00)....

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `HAVING` clauses are the wrong way to check for presence of a condition.  Instead of using the concatenated value, just use:

```
HAVING MAX(vi.interest_id IN (17)) > 0
```

When you do:

```
HAVING interests IN (17)
```

Then you are comparing a string to a number.  The string gets silently converted to a number.  In this case, only the first element is converted.  So, if the `interests` starts with "17," then it matches, otherwise it does not.

Also, note that your method of using `distinct` in `group_concat()` is fine, as long as there are not too many interests and skills.  If there were 100 of each for a vacancy, then the intermediate result would have 10,000 rows -- and take longer to process.  However, with just a handful of each, the method is fine.

Comment: There are only around 30 interest maxs and 10 skills max, with a maximum of 3 per vacancy. Not planning on upgrading these any time soon. :)
Your answer works perfectly thank you!